# Reducing Function to be Expressed in Terms of 1 Trigonometric Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am looking for a way to express $\tan(x) + \sec(x)$ as a function expressed in terms of a single trigonometric function. So far I have it down to:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x} + 1}{\cos(x)}
$$

Is there a more clean way to define this. Basically I have:

$$
y = \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x} + 1}{\cos(x)}
$$

and I need to express $x(y)$.

Comment: If you CAREFULLY draw the graph of $y=\tan x+\sec x$ you'll see it looks like a tangent function but with twice the period of the usual tangent function.

Comment: In high-school geometry I learned that if an arc of a circle subtends one angle with its vertex at the center and one with its vertex _on the circle_, then one of those has exactly twice the angle measure of the other. Now apply that to the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the arc from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos x,\sin x)$, and let the vertex _on_ the circle by $(-1,0)$. From the triangle with vertices $(-1,0)$, $(\cos x,0)$, and $(\cos x,\sin x)$, using "tan = opp/adj", you immediately get $\tan(x/2)=(\sin x)/(1+\cos x)$.  To me that's a way of recognizing occasions for the use of the latter identity.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your mathematical knowledge on this subject is impressive. I am interested in learning more. The problem I am solving is directly related to the Mercator projection. Do you have any recomended readings? I have Map Projections Used by the U.S. Geological Survey by John Snyder, as well as a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& \tan x + \sec x = \frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos y + 1}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\sin y}{1+\cos y} \right)} = \frac{1}{\tan\frac y 2} \\[15pt] = {} & \cot\frac y 2 = \cot\left(\frac{\frac\pi2 - x}{2}\right) = \cot\left(\frac\pi4-\frac x2\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $y=\dfrac\pi2-x$.

One of many tangent half-angle formulas says
$$
\tan x+\sec x = \tan\left(\frac\pi4 + \frac x 2\right).
$$
Privately I think of this as the "cartographer's tangent half-angle formula" because of the occurrence of the function $x\mapsto\log(\tan x+\sec x)$ in the Mercator projection.  The Mercator projection is characterized ("characterized" in the precisely defined mathematical sense of the word) by the fact that that compass bearings correspond to directions on the map, so that, for example $13^\circ$ east of north on the earth always corresponds to $13^\circ$ clockwise from straight up on the map, regardless of geographic location.

Comment: How does $\frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos y + 1}{\sin y}$?

Comment: Since $y=\frac\pi2-x$, one has $\sin x = \cos y$ and $\cos x = \sin y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan x + \sec x = \dfrac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x} = \dfrac{(\sin(\frac{x}{2}) + \cos(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{(\cos(\frac{x}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x}{2}))(\cos(\frac{x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2}))} = \dfrac{\sin(\frac{x}{2}) + \cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\cos(\frac{x}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x}{2})} = \dfrac{\tan(\frac{x}{2}) + 1}{1 - \tan(\frac{x}{2})}$.

Let $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$, then:

$f(x) = f(t) = \dfrac{t + 1}{1 - t}$

Comment: Please: Write $\sin x$, $\cos x$, etc. rather than $sinx$, $cosx$, etc.  (I changed it.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1 \Rightarrow 1-\cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x)$$